# Bluetooth LE Device scan in background from iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I am working on to scan BLE in Background mode.

**Issue is not working in Background scan. Its working very fine in Foreground mode.**

Below is few code lines.

```
dispatch_queue_t centralQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.XXXXX.BLEback", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);// or however you want to create your dispatch_queue_t
manager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:centralQueue options:nil];
```

---

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central 
{
    if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {

        [self startScan];
    }

    if (![self supportLEHardware]) 
    {
        @throw ([NSError errorWithDomain:@"Bluetooth LE not supported"
                                    code:999
                                userInfo:nil]);
    }
}
```

---

```
- (void)startScan
{
    NSDictionary * options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:false] forKey:CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey];
    [manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:options];
}
```

**here i am passing nil as a services.**

I receive log in Devices section in Xcode. But not in application.

```
Notice>: (Error) Discovered unknown type for scan: {
        kCBAdvDataChannel = 37;
        kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
        kCBAdvDataManufacturerData = <00003962 6708f4c1 00000000 00d02b00 20d03300 20d03300 20>;
        kCBAdvDataWSaturated = 0;
        kCBAdvDataWlanRSSI = 0;
    }, -51, puck type: 57
```

Comment: Please show more code - in particular your `centralManagerDidUpdateState` delegate method and where you perform the `scanForPeripheralsWithServices` in relation to receiving the powered on state in that delegate method

Comment: @Paulw11 Updated question with code lines.

Comment: Have you tried the LightBlue app from the app store to see if your peripheral is discoverable?

Comment: @Paulw11 Not yet. let me check...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot scan for `nil` services in the background - you must specify the service(s) that you are interested in.  From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBCentralManager/scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options:)

> Apps that have specified the bluetooth-central background mode are
>   allowed to scan while in the background. That said, they must
>   explicitly scan for one or more services by specifying them in the
>   serviceUUIDs parameter.

Comment: I think so, But which serviceUUIDs required. Is it relates to Hardware services ? https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServicesHome.aspx

Comment: You need to identify the service that your peripheral is advertising.  LightBlue can help with this or you can use your app in foreground mode to discover the services - for example heart rate is 0x180d

Comment: Is LightBlue app scan in background ?

Comment: No, but it will show you the services that your peripheral is advertising

Comment: OK, Let me check.. Do you have any idea how to achieve this Background scan stuff ?

Comment: Yes, you need to pass the UUIDs of the services that you want to scan for when you start the scan.

Comment: In Background scan, Actual issue is, when i pass nil as services, I got above values {Notice>: (Error) Discovered unknown type for scan: } in Device console. Not in Application. So i think there is something need to change will solve my issues.

Comment: **You cannot pass nil and expect to get call backs in your application**. It doesn't matter what you see in the device console.  The documentation I quoted in my answer is quite clear on this

Comment: Achieved. Problem with hardware side. Thanks for your time to support. accepted answer.. Peripheral was not advertising services, That is issue.

Answer (score 3):

For your app to continue to receive Bluetooth updates in the background, you need to add a `UIBackgroundModes` entry to your `Info.plist` and include the value `bluetooth-central` in the list.